# How to change default bar graph behaviour in Altair?

Tags: altair

Unable to figure out how to do a side by side bar plot in altair.

I have tried to do the following

```
(alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
        x="GroupSize:N",
        y="count(GroupSize):Q",
        color="Transported:N",))
```

it gives the following result
[image]

I want something like this https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks/bar.html#grouped-bar-chart-with-offset (without the offset part).
[image]

I don't see a parameter which I can tune to get a side by side bar graph instead of a stacked graph.

Comment: `offset` is how side by side bars are implemented in vega-lite/altair. Is there any particular reason you don't want to use it?